# Changing from sqlserver to mysql using efcore

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

i was previously using MSSQLSERVER in my project, then i switched to a mysql database using ef core by installing the pomelo mysql client and using that in my configure services. when i try to update the new mysql database using the previous migrations i had gotten from mssql i am getting a bunch of errors
the most annoying error was:

```
 Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (4ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE TABLE `Activities` (
          `Id` uniqueidentifier(36) NOT NULL,
          `Title` nvarchar(max) NULL,
          `Description` nvarchar(max) NULL,
          `Category` nvarchar(max) NULL,
          `Date` datetime2(6) NOT NULL,
          `City` nvarchar(max) NULL,
          `Venue` nvarchar(max) NULL,
          CONSTRAINT `PK_Activities` PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
      );
fail: API.Program[0]
      An error occured during migration
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corre
sponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'uniqueidentifier(36) NOT NULL,
    `Title` nvarchar(max) NULL,
    `Descriptio' at line 2
```

the migration file that the error is pointing to:

```
namespace Persistence.Migrations
{
    public partial class ActivityEntityAdded : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Activities",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false),
                    Title = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    Description = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    Category = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    Date = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
                    City = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    Venue = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Activities", x => x.Id);
                });
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "Activities");
        }
    }
}
```

can someone please tell me how to fix this error? or does mysql not support guids as of yet?
Please any input will be much appreciated!

Comment: @IanKemp The problematic code is auto generated by EF Core tools.

Comment: Migrations generated for one provider cannot be used with another. See [Migrations with Multiple Providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/providers?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) section of EF Core documentation.

Comment: @IvanStoev Generated by EF Core tools **for MSSQL**. Then the asker tried to run the same migrations on MySQL, and guess what it didn't work. Instead of doing research as to why, they then threw a question at Stack Overflow hoping we would solve all their problems for them.

Comment: wow ok. so i have to recreate all the code again from scratch using mysql?

Comment: @IanKemp But you should admit that EF Core approach is not so intuitive, especially for people coming from EF6 where generated migrations are database agnostic, and the documentation can easily be missed.

Comment: @IvanStoev Or, users could have basic, fundamental knowledge of the DBMSes they're working with, and/or read the official documentation that is provided, instead of relying on assumptions from other versions of the product.

Comment: Recommend adding pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql tag to get further help w/ that provider.